# How can I disable users in my active directory domain to access APIs secured with Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have an AD app registration for an API in azure which I generate client secret keys for other applications to authenticate and access my API.  Each client gets a separate secret key.

What I did not realize with this setup is that normal users in the AD domain are also allowed to just log into the API.

How can I disable this so that just clients using the generated secret keys will have access?

Answer (score 0):

If web api app is protected by azure ad , you need to acquire access token to access that web api . If you want to deny some AAD users to access api app , you could firstly set `User assignment required` for accessing the api app :
[image]

Then [assign a user or group to an enterprise app in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-coreapps-assign-user-azure-portal) , only assigned users could access that app .